# how to select files and folders on both Midnight Commander panels with the same name?

Tags: mc, panel

So we have Midnight Commander and 2 different folders - first on the left panel(folder1) and second on the right panel (folder2) panel.

There's a need to select ("highlight", like by pressing <kbd>Ins</kbd> key) files and folders in folder1 and folder2 with the same names , but - **only with names** (irrespective of differences in size, date etc.).

Any ideas how to do it in MC?

Comment: click on them with the mouse

Comment: Explain it better. You have two folders on __each__ panel, right? What do you mean with "select"? Do you want to mark them? What do you intend to do with those matching directories?

Comment: yes, I have folder1 on the left panel and folder2 on the right. Both folders have some equal files and sub-folders (equal means by name and nothing more). I need select them like throughout pressing Ins key or by pattern with + key (so "highlight" them)

Comment: OK then, each panel displays a directory content (the usual behavior). Your initial wording could lead us to believe that each panel contained two directories. Please [edit] your question with that information. You may upload a picture to display those initial panels. You want to mark the directories and files common to both that have the same name. I'm afraid that can't be done (not even with _Compare Directories_). If you tell us what you want to do with the marked files, maybe we can help you coming up with a user menu entry to act on them.

Comment: thanks I done it.
The general idea is - select (highlight) all files and folders in folder1 that have corresponding by name items in folder2 (so folder2 is like pattern for selection). Than I have to copy selected files from folder1 to folder3 using mc file copying interface (there are some important options). Any of these 3 folders can by an ftp-folder so I cannot use command line tricks like ls -a and so on.